# What does 'BS' stands for in sublime text on macOS?

Tags: macos, encoding, sublimetext3

in macOS, I use zsh terminal ,then input command 'man sort > sort-man.txt'.
When open sort-man.txt with Sublime text, I see many 'BS'.
What does 'BS' stands for in sublime text on macOS??
It can be some encoding issue??
[question picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzjQb.jpg)

Comment: You can include an image link here to better illustrate your question.

Comment: [man-sort.jpg](https://postimg.cc/image/i4y7dh6ql/)

Comment: It it better to store the file some where and post a link in your question, so people can reproduce your issue. I think not doing that is why you get a few downvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

The `man` command outputs a “bold” character by printing the character, then printing a backspace character, then printing the character again. Thus:

```
:; man sort | hexdump -C | head
00000000  0a 53 4f 52 54 28 31 29  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.SORT(1)        |
00000010  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 42 53 44 20 47  |           BSD G|
00000020  65 6e 65 72 61 6c 20 43  6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64 73 20  |eneral Commands |
00000030  4d 61 6e 75 61 6c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |Manual          |
00000040  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  53 4f 52 54 28 31 29 0a  |        SORT(1).|
00000050  0a 4e 08 4e 41 08 41 4d  08 4d 45 08 45 0a 20 20  |.N.NA.AM.ME.E.  |
              ^  ^  ^
              |  |  +--- ASCII N
              |  +------ ASCII Backspace
              +--------- ASCII N
```

Way back in the days of physical terminals that printed on paper, this would have the effect of overstriking the character, making it appear bolder.

These days, your terminal emulator app interprets a sequence like this by changing the color or font of the character.

I guess Sublime Text shows the backspace character as `BS`.

Consulting the [man man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/man.1.html), I find this under “TIPS”:

> To get a plain text version of a man page, without backspaces and underscores, try
>
> ```
> # man foo | col -b > foo.mantxt
> ```